# Problems with compiling multiple AS3 packages w/ant and mxmlc

Tags: actionscript-3, ant, mxml, mxmlc, bigbluebutton

I'm trying to extend the BigBlueButton client with some proprietary classes. Specifically the phone module, where I added a file with my own code. When I write my own package name (org.mydomain.module.test ...) within the file, the compiler fails because it can't find my class from the mxml file. But when I use the original package name (org.bigbluebutton.module.phone ...) it compiles fine. Obviously when I use a different package name, the file is not included in the compilation. How can I change this?

This fails:

```
package org.mydomain.module.test 
{
  public class MyTestClass
  {
    // code here
  }
}
```

But this works:

```
package org.bigbluebutton.modules.phone.test
{
  public class MyTestClass
  {
    // code here
  }
}
```

FYI: BigBlueButton uses ant to compile the client.

Comment: You didn't say where you put the files on disk, the package name should match the file's path in your project. Is that the case in both examples?

Comment: You got a point there; I placed my own package files together with the original ones. Will move them to the correct directory and try to compile again. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for the solution; you may write it as an answer instead of a comment and get the credit for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say where you put the files on disk, the package name should match the file's path in your project. Is that the case in both examples?

So when the package name is: `org.mydomain.module.test`

The class file should be saved in the path:

```
my_project_path/src/org/mydomain/module/test
```